# SSIS Move file if name exists in dbo.table data

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I am using SSIS 2010.  I have a folder with a number of files inside, and am required to:

1. check if filename exists in a table of data - so, is the filename also inside a column of data (this is a list of files that have met a certain criteria)
2. if the filename has a match then move it to another location, if not then leave it as is and then move onto the next file to check (foreachloop I guess).

Now I have done moves with variables (e.g. month.txt etc) but cannot figure out how to check against a table of data.

Can anyone help please? Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the foreach loop which loops over the files in your directory:

Create an Execute SQL Task. Set the SQL Statement to

`SELECT count(*) as countrecords FROM ETL_Log WHERE ImportedFname='whatever.txt'`

You'll have to set this to an expression of course, so that whatever.txt is replaced with the filename from your foreach loop.

Double click on the Execute SQL task. Under the General tab, set the 'ResultSet' property to 'Single row'. This way it's expecting a single output from your query - a count of the number of times this file has been imported.

Under 'Result Set', set result name to 0, and variablename to User::count.
So each time your loop looks at a new file in the directory, you'll know whether that file has been previously moved or not. (assuming you write to that table at the end of your import).

Then you can double click the green arrow (precedence constraint) that connects  the execute sql task to the next task (moving the file). Set the evaluation operation to 'Expression and Constraint'. Set the expression to @[User::count]==0

Now, when the exec statement counts zero rows in your table with the filename in question, your user count variable gets set to zero, and the precedence constraint evaluates to true, thus moving on to the next step of moving the file. If user::count is not equal to zero (i.e. already moved), it will not do anything further with this file, and move onto the next file in the foreach loop. I use this type of setup on a lot of my ssis packages and it works well. Hope it helps.